# command mkdir -p returns: "mkdir: can't create directory '/drives/f/': Permission denied" when use full path on mobaxterm on Windows

Tags: bash, permissions, cygwin, mkdir, mobaxterm

Command:

`mkdir -p /drives/f/_/cache`

returns:

> mkdir: can't create directory '/drives/f/': Permission denied

in MobaXterm on Windows.

`mkdir -p cache`

in /drives/f/_/ works fine.

Any workaround on this assuming I can't go with relative path here? I can't change permissions for /drives so I think there is the main problem. Maybe there is a solution in MobaXterm allowing to use full path without /drives at the beginning?

Comment: Why do you need the -p option, if /drives/f/_/ already exists?

Comment: mkdir -p is used in many times in linux script, I just don't want to change every such command to if-elseif equivalent

Comment: Ok, i suggest to check directories permissions, all parents should have at least the x permission

Comment: all parents have 777 permission, excluding /drives (555  - no write)

Comment: I don't know anything about MobaXterm, so this is guesswork.
It looks like `mkdir` can see '/drives' but not '/drives/f'.  Maybe it's a case sensitivity issue.  Try `mkdir -p /drives/F/_/cache`.  If it's not that, maybe there's something else unexpected about the paths seen by `mkdir`.  If you run `pwd` in '/drives/f', what does it print?  (Hoping that `pwd` and `mkdir` process paths in the same way.)

Comment: It is case insensitive - `mkdir -p /drives/F/_/cache` returns same error. Also, pwd in `/drives/f` returns:
/drives/f

Comment: What does `mount` show?

Comment: F: on /drives/f type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used workaround changing:

> /drives/f/_/cache

to:

> f:/_/cache

by using command:

`BASE_DIR=$(pwd | cut -f 3 -d '/'):/$(pwd | cut -f 4- -d '/')`

and it works flawless in MobaXterm.